# Netlogo: measure distance from turtle to each patch and perform calculations from this

Tags: netlogo

new Netlogo user here and I'm feeling pretty stuck. I’m trying to model turtles picking patches for a home range. Currently, all patches have a food benefit 0.1 or 1.0, and the turtle picks patches to add to its home range by looking for the next-closest patch with benefit 1.0. It automatically adds any patches it crosses with benefit 0.1 on its way to selecting the high-benefit patches. This code appears to work fine for this behavior.

However, I’d like the turtle to do something a little different than just pick the next-closest patch with value 1.0. Instead:

1. I want the turtle to look at all patches in the landscape, and calculate the distance from its home range center to each patch in the landscape.
2. It should then calculate value to the turtle (“value-to-me”) by dividing the patch's food benefit by the distance to that patch. So, benefit/distance = value-to-me.
3. It should then pick the next destination patch by highest value-to-me.

I have tried everything I can think of, with no success. How and when does the calculation for distance to all patches occur? How do I calculate value-to-me? I realize these calculations are turtle-specific since each turtle will have its own set of distances measured to each patch on the landscape. As such, I’ve tried things like “let value-to-me [benefit / distance myself], set destination max-one-of value-to-me” (and every possible variation I can think of).

As I said, I’m really new to this. Please let me know if more details are needed to help with this question. Thank you very much in advance for any assistance!

```
;;------------------------------------Run model-----------------------------
;; benefit is the food benefit on a patch, either 0.1 or 1.0
;; sum-v is the total food benefits acquired by the turtle as it picks patches for its home range
;; threshold-v is the total benefits required in order to satisfy home range requirements.
;; patches are used? = true once picked, so turtle can only pick unused patches.
;; start-patch is the origin (center) of the home range, from which turtle picks patches.

to go  
   ask turtles
    [pick-territory]
   tick
end

to pick-territory 
     ifelse sum-v < threshold-v  ;; if the turtle's sum-v is less than threshold-v, then keep picking
      [  
          ;--This line works:---
             set destination min-one-of patches with [ benefit >= 1 and used? = false ][ distance myself ] 
          ;; This line appears to work so that turtle decides which is next-closest high-benefit, unused patch from its home range center.

          ;--BUT...this is what I want to do:---
          ;; Calculate distance to all patches from start-patch (turtle's home range origin).
          ;; Calculate "value-to-me" as the benefit (of patch) divided by distance to that patch from turtle's start-patch.
          ;; Set destination to highest value-to-me patch.
          ;; I've tried all sorts of things to do this, to no avail.
          ;; For example, the following code doesn't work...
               let value-to-me [benefit / distance myself] 
               set destination max-one-of value-to-me  
          ;; So I'm hoping for help with all this. 

          ;--After it sets its destination, the turtle does the following:       
          face destination 
          forward 1 ;; move forward 1 and do all these things....
          set memory lput patch-here memory  ;; turtle adds patch to memory of home range as it moves across it

          if patch-here = destination
            [
              set sum-v sum-v + benefit ;; monitors total sum-v acquired as the sum of all benefits from patches 
              set patches-picked patches-picked + 1 ;; counts the # of patches picked for home range
              set used? true ;; changes patch to used? true so knows it's no longer available
              let this-turtle self
              set owner this-turtle ;; adds the turtle's name to the patch so the patch knows who owns it
              move-to start-patch ;; return to origin and find a new available destination patch
            ]

          if patch-here != destination  ;; meanwhile, if the patch isn't the destination (turtle moves across it to get there), then do the following:
            [
              if used? = false  ;; if it's an available patch...still add it to the home range, add +1 to patches-picked, add its benefits to sum-v, etc.
              [ set sum-v sum-v + benefit  
                set patches-picked patches-picked + 1  
                set used? true
                let this-turtle self
                set owner this-turtle
              ]
            ]

      ]
      [stop] ;; stop if sum-v => threshold-v.
end
```

Comment: A turtle can `move-to max-one-of patches [benefit / distance myself]`. (But make sure you think about your chosen topology, as it affects distance).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks Alan! (And it seems so obvious now!) Thank you again.